# Strange Character in my Bash prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I'm somewhat new to Bash prompts, but I was finally able to get things somewhat working. However, I have a strange character at the beginning of my prompt:

[image: Screenshot of prompt]

Here's my actual `PS1` prompt:

```
PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\h\a${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

Can anyone spot the problem? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Be wary of strange characters lurking around your prompts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the last `\]` to end the title bar sequence.  The result is that it's eating up some chars & displaying a weird character at the front.

try one of these:

- `\[\033]2; \u@\h \007\]`
- `\[\e]0;\u@\h\a\]`

Comment: @TK : I've also updated http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14113/5614

Answer (score 3):

The start of your prompt has a fragment in it: `\[\e]2;\` that should probably be something more like: `\[e[0;32m\]` to set the colour green.

`\[` begins a sequence of non-printing characters. `\e` is the ascii escape character and the colour green is `0;32m`

There is an excellent break down of the elements of a coloured prompt on the Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

Comment: Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14113/5614, here, I'm told that in order to set the window title, I need this escape sequence. What should I do?

Comment: So you have two separate issues: the broken prompt and you want to set the terminal title. I'd fix the first - using the approach I have suggested above, and then that should allow you to achieve the second.